# Looking up a value in a column for most matching values in two other columns

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, lookup

Into a pandas dataframe I retrieve via an API option chain data for a stock. In the column 'expiration' you can see that in this test case I have three option series with expiries at respectively: 2019-08-15, 2019-09-15 and 2019-10-15.

What I want to achieve is:

- for each option series (3 in this test case)
- lookup the 'strike' price that is closest to 'undPrice' (=price of the underlying stock)
- for the 'strike' price that is closest to 'undPrice' look up the corresponding value in 'IV_model' (=implied volatility)
- fill that value in the column 'desired_outcome' for all the option combinations of that expiration series (so, in this test case three times block with identical values)
- So, there are basically three look-ups within one series of data.

This is the code for a test case that comes close to my live environment:

```
import pandas as pd
undPrice = 202

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['expiration', 'strike', 'undPrice', 'IV_model', 'desired_outcome'])
df['expiration'] = ['2019-08-15', '2019-08-15', '2019-08-15', '2019-08-15', '2019-08-15', '2019-08-15', '2019-08-15', '2019-08-15', '2019-09-15', '2019-09-15', '2019-09-15', '2019-09-15', '2019-09-15', '2019-09-15', '2019-09-15', '2019-09-15', '2019-09-15', '2019-09-15', '2019-10-15', '2019-10-15', '2019-10-15', '2019-10-15', '2019-10-15', '2019-10-15', '2019-10-15', '2019-10-15', '2019-10-15', '2019-10-15']
df['expiration'] = df['expiration'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(str(x), utc=True,format='%Y-%m-%d'))
df['strike'] = [170, 175, 180, 185, 190, 195, 200, 205, 165, 170, 175, 180, 185, 190, 195, 200, 205, 210, 160, 165, 170, 175, 180, 185, 190, 195, 200, 205]
df['undPrice'] = [undPrice, undPrice, undPrice, undPrice, undPrice, undPrice, undPrice, undPrice, undPrice, undPrice, undPrice, undPrice, undPrice, undPrice, undPrice, undPrice, undPrice, undPrice, undPrice, undPrice, undPrice, undPrice, undPrice, undPrice, undPrice, undPrice, undPrice, undPrice]
df['IV_model'] = [0.28, 0.27, 0.26, 0.25, 0.24, 0.23, 0.22, 0.21, 0.35, 0.34, 0.33, 0.32, 0.31, 0.30, 0.29, 0.28, 0.27, 0.26, 0.42, 0.41, 0.40, 0.39, 0.38, 0.37, 0.36, 0.35, 0.34, 0.33]
df['IV_model'] = df['IV_model'].map('{:.2%}'.format)
df['desired_outcome'] = [0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.34, 0.34, 0.34, 0.34, 0.34, 0.34, 0.34, 0.34, 0.34, 0.34]
df['desired_outcome'] = df['desired_outcome'].map('{:.2%}'.format)
print(df)
```

And this would the (desired) outcome (obviously 'desired_outcome' filled in manually):

```
                  expiration  strike  undPrice IV_model desired_outcome
0  2019-08-15 00:00:00+00:00     170       202   28.00%          22.00%
1  2019-08-15 00:00:00+00:00     175       202   27.00%          22.00%
2  2019-08-15 00:00:00+00:00     180       202   26.00%          22.00%
3  2019-08-15 00:00:00+00:00     185       202   25.00%          22.00%
4  2019-08-15 00:00:00+00:00     190       202   24.00%          22.00%
5  2019-08-15 00:00:00+00:00     195       202   23.00%          22.00%
6  2019-08-15 00:00:00+00:00     200       202   22.00%          22.00%
7  2019-08-15 00:00:00+00:00     205       202   21.00%          22.00%
8  2019-09-15 00:00:00+00:00     165       202   35.00%          28.00%
9  2019-09-15 00:00:00+00:00     170       202   34.00%          28.00%
10 2019-09-15 00:00:00+00:00     175       202   33.00%          28.00%
11 2019-09-15 00:00:00+00:00     180       202   32.00%          28.00%
12 2019-09-15 00:00:00+00:00     185       202   31.00%          28.00%
13 2019-09-15 00:00:00+00:00     190       202   30.00%          28.00%
14 2019-09-15 00:00:00+00:00     195       202   29.00%          28.00%
15 2019-09-15 00:00:00+00:00     200       202   28.00%          28.00%
16 2019-09-15 00:00:00+00:00     205       202   27.00%          28.00%
17 2019-09-15 00:00:00+00:00     210       202   26.00%          28.00%
18 2019-10-15 00:00:00+00:00     160       202   42.00%          34.00%
19 2019-10-15 00:00:00+00:00     165       202   41.00%          34.00%
20 2019-10-15 00:00:00+00:00     170       202   40.00%          34.00%
21 2019-10-15 00:00:00+00:00     175       202   39.00%          34.00%
22 2019-10-15 00:00:00+00:00     180       202   38.00%          34.00%
23 2019-10-15 00:00:00+00:00     185       202   37.00%          34.00%
24 2019-10-15 00:00:00+00:00     190       202   36.00%          34.00%
25 2019-10-15 00:00:00+00:00     195       202   35.00%          34.00%
26 2019-10-15 00:00:00+00:00     200       202   34.00%          34.00%
27 2019-10-15 00:00:00+00:00     205       202   33.00%          34.00%
```

I am a relative beginner in Python programming, I came a long way already but this is out of my league. I hope that somebody can help me out with this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

Create a dict of the expiration to IV_model by finding the min distance between undPrice and strike.

```
desiredOutcomeMap = df.groupby('expiration').apply(lambda x: df.loc[abs(x['undPrice']-x['strike']).idxmin(), 'IV_model']).to_dict()
```

Then map it to the original df.

```
df['desired_outcome'] = df['expiration'].map(desiredOutcomeMap)
```